# how to model introduction of wolves to population growth model for deer?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

the info given:
A different method of population control is to introduce a predator. If the forest service introduces wolves, (you may assume wolves were extinct in this area in the past), for every 20 wolves, 80 deer per year will die. The service is considering introducing a pack of 100 wolves. As long as the deer population is 10 times the wolf population, the wolf population will grow at the rate of 10% per year; if the deer population is between 5 and 10 times the wolf population,then the wolf population will grow at the rate of 5% per year; if the deer population is between 2 and 5 times the wolf population, the wolf population will grow at 1% per year; and if the deer population is less than twice the wolf population, then the wolf population will decrease at 2% per year. Using the model a=1(with no hunting licenses)project what the introduction of wolves will do to the deer population

we were ask to model $P=kP^a$ given specific a values. when a=1 i got $P(t)=Ae^{kt}$
so using using that for the deer population how would you incorporate wolves.
my current thoughts where on using $P=rP(1-\frac{p}{k})$ so that k represented the changing population of the deer which operates as the wolves population capacity.

I'm just not sure

1. if this is the write approach
2. where to even begin adding this to the $P(t)=Ae^{kt}$

Comment: It looks like you population of wolves $W$ and your population of deer $D$ evolves according to the system $$\frac{dD}{dt}=kD-4W$$


\begin{equation*}
\frac{dW}{dt}=\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            W/10: & \quad D\geq 10W \\
            W/20: & 5W \leq D <10W \\
            W/100: & 2W \leq D <5W \\
            -W/50: &D<2W
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

Comment: @MatthewPilling i have not done anything similar/seen anything written similar to that in my calc1 class. being similar to piecewise functions does that mean 4w becomes $\frac{dW}{dt}$? Could you possibly show me how this works?

Comment: Here's how I thought about $\frac{dW}{dt}$.

Let $D(t)$ denote the population of deer $t$ years since the introduction of the pack of $100$ wolves. Define $W(t)$ similarly for the wolf population. Since each wolf kills four deer each year, the population of deer at year $t+1$ will *decrease* by $\approx4W(t)$ deer. We're also assuming the population of deer increases at a rate of $k$ percent per year, so the population of deer will *increase* by $\approx kD(t)$ deer in year $t+1$. Putting these together have $$D(t+1)-D(t)\approx kD(t)-4W(t)$$

Comment: If this is your problem for Calc I homework there is probably a more suitable approach using the tools that you have.

Comment: @MatthewPilling its a group project.no one in the group can figure out this problem. the class covers only the first 4 chapters of this [book](http://scidiv.bellevuecollege.edu/dh/Calculus_all/Calculus_all.html) the class is functions, limits, graphs, derivatives, derivatives and graphs, then integrals.

Comment: what the teacher suggested looking at: A cup of hot soup is in a room with a temperature of 70° F.  When first poured, the soup was 200° F, and 5 minutes later it was 150° F
 (a)  In this example, $a = 70° F  and  f(0) = 200°F  so  f '(t) = k( f(t) – 70 ) and  f(t) = 70 + (200 – 70) e^{kt}  = 70 + 130e^{kt}$ .   We can use the information that  $f(5) = 150° F$ to find the value of  k  and an equation for  $f(t) :150 = f(5) = 70 + 130. e^{k5}    so  k = \frac{1}{5}ln( 80/130 ) ≈–0.0971  and f(t) = 70 + 130e^{(–0.0971)t}$